LED exposed different lights causing changes in polarity
I was playing around with an LED (lets call it D1) and I am somewhat familiar with the photoelectric effect so I took a different LED (lets call it D2) and directed the light into D1. D2 is a cooler (blue) LED than D1 which is a neutral (white) LED. When I do this I see a positive voltage from the anode to the cathode. I think this tracks with what I know about the photoelectric effect. The more curious discovery I found is when I took two of the same type of D1 diodes and repeated the process. When I did this the voltage became negative?! I do not understand why this happens and I was wondering if someone has an explanation to the phenomenon. I am assuming it has something to do with the wavelength of the light but I could be totally off.



Probably something to do with the heterojunction structure of modern blue LEDs.

White and off-white LED's use an added fluorescent layer to make a more complete spectrum. Try with pure-color LED's, which can make useful photodetectors.
